# With useState How do I set initial state to an empty Array, and then add empty Objects to that Array when I button is Clicked?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to mount a component which will mount children components based on how many times a user hits a **+ ingredient** icon as shown here (this screenshot shows one hardcoded to render)

[image]

I want to achieve this by setting an ingredients state to initially be an empty array

```
const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([]);
```

And then have the onClick action of the plus icon add an empty object to this array, while preserving any objects that have been added/modified

```
  const addElementToArray = () => {
    setIngredients((prevIngredients) => [
      ...prevIngredients, {}
    ]);
  }
```

However, the current behavior is a bit mysterious to me.

When console.log(ingredients) it is initially an empty array, great

However, when I click the **+** icon once it transforms to:

```
[{…}, [object Object]: {…}]
```

and then I believe back to an empty object

[image]

And finally, when I click it again the component crashes with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: prevIngredients is not iterable
```

I'm unsure how to successfully get the functionality I want, any help is appreciated.

Full file below:

```
const RecipeCreate = props => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [ ingredients, setIngredients ] = useState([]);
  const [ recipeTitle, setRecipeTitle ] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ingredients)
    renderIngredientComponents()
  }, [ingredients])

  //will render IngredientDetailsInput for each obj in ingredients
  //and will be updated using callbacks from that child component
  const renderIngredientComponents = () => {
    if (ingredients.length > 0) {
      return ingredients.map((index, ingredient) => {
        return <IngredientDetailsInput 
                  key={index}
                  position={index}
                  updateIngredientArray={updateIngredientArray}
                  removeIngredient={removeIngredient}
                />
      })
    }
  }


  //failing function
  const addElementToArray = () => {
    setIngredients((prevIngredients) => [
      ...prevIngredients, {}
    ]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
          <div>
            <label>Recipe Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="recipeTitle"
              value={recipeTitle}
              onChange={e => setRecipeTitle(e.target.value)}/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Ingredients</p>
            {renderIngredientComponents()}
            <div>
              <p onClick={()=> addElementToArray()}>+ ingredient</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default RecipeCreate;
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but your length check in `renderIngredientComponents ` is redundant. Also, your `removeIngredient` and `updateIngredientArray` are using the state setter incorrectly

Comment: Thanks @Phil I haven't even begun troubleshooting those lol - they'll have problems I'm sure. For now they're essentially pseudo-code

Comment: That call to `setIngredients` you show is ok, the other two are not. You must build new objects, not update in-place, and call the setter with them. That's the react way.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, **complete** and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now, this won't compile due to all the missing functions (`updateIngredientArray`, `removeIngredient` and `handleSubmit`)

Comment: You definitely do no need that effect hook and your `map` args are back-to-front

Comment: Made some minor corrections [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-morning-jthq5f?file=/src/App.tsx) but in general, this is not reproducible

Comment: Thanks @Phil I’ll update it to be reproducible when I get home

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems here:

```
setIngredients(ingredients.splice(ingredients[position], 1))
```

- `splice` mutates the array it's called on - but `ingredients` is stateful, and state should never be mutated. Mutating state often results in confusing and unpredictable behavior, and should not be done in React.
- `splice` returns the removed element, not the mutated array

You need

```
setIngredients(ingredients.filter((_, i) => i !== position));
```

Also

```
setIngredients(ingredients[position] = details)
```

I know the comment says it's not implemented yet, but it's also causing a bug - you're passing `details` to `setIngredients`, so that it's no longer an array.

```
setIngredients(ingredients[position] = details)
```

is equivalent to

```
ingredients[position] = details;
setIngredients(details)
```

I'm not sure what logic you want there, but it's causing problems - remove that part entirely until you implement it properly, else it'll mess up your state.

Comment: Correct, thanks @Phil probably shouldn't have included them.